# How can I maintain the application state in RESTful api in golang

Tags: go

In my case, I don't have a browser as a client. I will be using HTTP client so I can not maintain the client-side session. Therefore how can I maintain the application state?

Comment: This isn't really about Go at all.   You cannot have both requirements that you want a REST-ful architecture and no client state; that's a contradiction.   Pick one.   (Otherwise you just have a library of resources, not an application.)

Comment: @BadZen a REST application is stateless by definition. "A library of resources" is the textbook definition of a REST application. You may be confusing REST with JSON-RPC (a very common misunderstanding, particularly in the Swagger camp that sees REST as the new SOAP). See https://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html https://restfulapi.net/rest-architectural-constraints/ and https://restfulapi.net/hateoas/ for more info.

Comment: Or you may be not reading my comment.   You're saying exactly the thing I said - you don't get to have a REST-ful application where the client has no state.  You can satisfy at most one of those conditions.  Also, answers are for answers.   There is no answer, so you should not post a non-answer.

Comment: There is no requirement that a client of a REST application maintain client-side state. It can request all the data it needs, as it needs it, from the server.

Comment: There are two requirements that OP indiciated: 1) per-session state not kept on client side, and 2) REST-fulness.  My statement was that these are mutually exclusive, not that every REST-ful architecture must have client state.   (We really ought to recognize the difference between NOT(A AND B) and A IMPLIES B as programmers, no?)   Anyway, we're OT so I'm ghosting.

Comment: @Martin: regardless of the definition of REST, _why_ can't you maintain the state you need with the http client? State doesn't require a browser.

Answer (score 1):

In a true RESTful application, there is no session. The only thing that might be in a client-side session would be a simple authentication token, and a non-browser client should be able to send authentication with every request as necessary.

Comment: What is the "authentication token"? What does connect that "token" to a user account?

Comment: @zerkms that's an application-specific detail that will vary from one case to the next.

Comment: Can it be a random string that is then stored in a database in a `auth token -> user id` table?

Comment: It can but that would not be particularly secure. That's well outside the scope of this question, though.

Comment: "It can" --- what I explained is a "session" though. PS: it would not be less secure than any other authentication token, like oauth v2 access token.

Comment: If you store token -> userID in the database, then anyone who gets ahold of the database can impersonate any user with an open session. It's more secure to store a cryptographic hash of the token, same as you would with a password.

Comment: Sure, my initial point is though, that "there is no session" turned into "It can" in like 4 minutes (since all that is too vague, and is not formalised anywhere).

Comment: Actually, that was in my answer from the beginning: "The only thing that might be in a client-side session would be a simple authentication token." This is a convenience often used in browser-based REST clients to avoid repeated authentication. There still isn't a "session", it's just a form of stored authentication.